# How can I find files quicker than find or locate?

Tags: search, find

I have been using find command to find files on my 1 tb hard disk. it takes very long. then I used locate which proved to be faster with regular update using updatedb. But the limitation of locate is that I cannot find files with certain size or modified/created time. can you suggest me any ideas on how to find files at more speed or in that case how to pipe output of locate command in a way that all other information like size, time, etc. can be displayed or redirected to a file.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the full `find` command including arguments which takes too long? Or `find` is slow with any arguments for you? On my system find scans the whole filesystem within 2 seconds (100GB).

Comment: I replaced the native "search option" with "gnome-do" http://do.davebsd.com/ quite some time ago, which lets you search for files of any kind and adds possibilities of quick access and extended sub-functionality, like open, edit, send to mail, open as command etc.. Maybe you find it helpful!

Comment: @Chaitanya Is my answer missing something you need?

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested me an Idea to use locate database with find to make it work faster which is as follows
find $(locate -d external.db 1.txt)
That is definitely much faster but it has a problem that it doesnt work on file names with spaces or any special character. Any ideas to refine the command are most welcome

Comment: @arrange: I'm not him but `find` takes several minutes to return on my media and image home server. `root@viashivan:/media/data1# find . -type f | wc -l` and rhe result is 2044791.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen an answer that comes near the wishes of Chaitanya. If you want to search on filename, a combination of locate, find, ls and grep could be sufficient. But I think Chaitanya want to search for example for 'all files created before 2011'. This can perfectly done with find, but I can imagine it will take a long time searching through 1TB (depends more on the amount of files, not necessarily the total size). To speed this up I think indexing is inevitable. The problem of locate (indexing with updatedb) is that it doesn't index creation time.

So what Chaitanya need is something that indexes the needed attributes of files (file name, file size, creation date, more?). And later something that can search on these attributes.  As far as I know there is no out-of-the-box solution for this on Ubuntu.

An important comment of Chaitanya: "Now the thing is that I am designing a php based web gui...". Because your problem sounds quite specific, maybe you want to build somehting yourself. Some suggestions:

- Index the files in a database (with cronjob) and use SQL to search.
- Use Lucene to index and search ([Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) for PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Use "find option Parameter". See "man find" more detail.
Use **locate** to find a document quickly and easily, eg. "locate *.jpg"

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested me an Idea to use locate database with find to make it work faster which is as follows find $(locate -d external.db 1.txt) That is definitely much faster but it has a problem that it doesnt work on file names with spaces or any special character. Any ideas to refine the command are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/). It has a daemon that waits for file changes and updates a database with all the metadata as possible, and a client that you can use to search for files. Note that it only indexes the user dir, not all the hard disk.

The main dawback is that it needs CPU time to index, so use it only if your computer has power to spare.

You will need to install both the server and client, they are named tracker and tracker-gui. If you search for tracker in the Software Center they are the two first matches. If you prefer to install them from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install tracker tracker-gui
```

Comment: Now the thing is that I am designing a php based web gui which will be accessed from a remote machine. so I am limited to use command line tools only. any ideas further are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Response to comment:

`ls -la "$(locate -d external.db "Duel of Fates (Darth ")"`

produces:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 4075134 2012-03-30 22:37 /home/user/Music/Star Wars: Episode 1 - Duel of Fates (Darth Maul's Theme).mp3
```

Thx @Oli in AskUbuntu chat for tipping me off to "something" to get around shell escapes

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested me an Idea to use locate database with find to make it work faster which is as follows find $(locate -d external.db 1.txt) That is definitely much faster but it has a problem that it doesnt work on file names with spaces or any special character. Any ideas to refine the command are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

The issue with locate is that it only collects file information occasionally on a regular cron schedule. You if you need mlocate to update its information, just run this

```
$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

If you need a solution that is more "real-time" and updates constantly, I would suggest going with something that is specifically designed to monitor your filesystem, like `tracker-gui` as Javier Rivera stated.

To redirect the output of `locate` to a file, just use an arrow `>` instead of the pipe `|` character. (One arrow will over write an output file if it already exists. Two arrows will append to an output file if it already exists.)

```
$ locate filename > output.txt  # Overwrite
$ locate filename >> output.txt # Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [gnome-search-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-search-tool)

It provides

- File content
- Modification date
- Size
- File emptiness
- Owner/Group
- Name pattern exclusion
- Name regular expression match
- Hidden and backup files

Answer (score 0):

> how to pipe output of locate command in a way that all other
>   information like size, time, etc. can be displayed or redirected to a
>   file.

Much time and effort was devoted to solving this problem in this answer:

- [How can I count files with a particular extension, and the directories they are in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023244/how-can-i-count-files-with-a-particular-extension-and-the-directories-they-are/1023474#1023474)

This code can be scaled down to your `locate` needs:

```
$ time locate -0 *.mp4 | xargs -0 ls -s

     4 /home/rick/askubuntu/subdir-A/1.mp4
     4 /home/rick/askubuntu/subdir-A/2.mp4
         ( ... SNIP ... )
  3684 /mnt/d/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-winsatmediafiles_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_51eff420121c1922/Clip_480_5sec_6mbps_h264.mp4
 35972 /mnt/old/home/rick/Videos/VID_20180701_233225.mp4

real    0m0.900s
user    0m0.826s
sys     0m0.084s
```

Breaking down `locate -0 *.mp4 | xargs -0 ls -s`:

- `locate -0` - The locate command usually prints a new line (`\n`) at the end of each entry. `0` instructs locate to separate entries with a null byte instead.
- `*.mp4` Locate all files ending in .mp4 (sound files)
- `|` is the pipe character. Whatever is printed by locate command doesn't go to the screen but is redirected to the next command.
- `xargs -0` - The xargs command takes entry by entry output from previous command (locate) and passes it to the next command. `-0` signifies entries are separated by null byte, rather than newline (`\n`) separator.
- `ls -s` The `ls` command is called by `xargs` and passed the file name to list. The `-s` flag tells `ls` to include the file size.

As you can see the process takes less than 1 second for over a million files in three Ubuntus and two Windows partitions.